# How do I take a subset of a string in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Given a string that represents the name of a person, how do I get the first two characters of this string as a new variable?

Is there a function in MATLAB that can do this, or do I need to program it in a MATLAB code file?

```
Jack --> Ja
Cleve --> Cl
```

Answer (score 6):

Strings are treated as arrays in matlab so you can use normal array notation.

```
personName = 'something';
firstTwoLetters = personName(1:2);
```

Comment: actually what Im trying to do is that i have a list of 2 names
 that are not on the worksapce im reading them from xls read and i want to get the first 2 letter ,ive tried to make the mfile but it gets an error function acro_profs= acro(profs)
for i=1:length(profs)
   
    
  aux = profs{i}
 acro_profs(i,:)=aux(1:2)% here it says exceeded matrix
end

Comment: @mona: you probably have to add some error checking.  It's hard to say though without a longer code snippet that clarifies what the variables "acro" and "profs" are.

Comment: This is two different problems:  Reading from Excel and String manipulation.  They should be posted as separate questions.